# Mean of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe, for example:

```
Val1    Val2
1        4
2        10
2        5
1        7
2        0
1        20
```

I want to get a mean of all numbers from Val2 that have Val1 value equal to 1 (in the same row). How can I do that without using loop?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what results are you getting? what do you expect as the final result?

Comment: Why do you wan to use a loop?

Comment: `df.loc[df['Val1'] == 1]['Val2'].mean()` is probably a good start. Maybe look at grouping the values and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
df.groupby(['Val1'])['Val2'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you just want the mean as a simple float number. In this case, you can do:

```
df[df["Val1"] == 1]["Val2"].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers should provide the correct answer as well, but I believe the most idiomatic way of doing this is the following:
`df.loc[df['Val1']==1, 'Val2'].mean()`